# How to navigate to new page on a placeholder event of jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery to navigate to page in select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075866/jquery-to-navigate-to-page-in-select-option)

I need to navigate to a new page on select of a particular option.
I am refering this [jquery mobile form](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4/docs/forms/forms-selects.html)

Here is my code...

```
<div class="ui-select">
             <select name="select-choice-5" id="select-choice-5"
                data-native-menu="false" tabindex="-1">
                <option>View details...</option>
                <option value="option1">Option1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option3</option>
                <option value="option4">Option4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

How to do it?

Comment: like this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075866/jquery-to-navigate-to-page-in-select-option

Comment: Yes exactly...Plsss post it as answer so that i can accept..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/vsw3r/4/

JS

```
$('.selectMe').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.val() != '') {
        $.mobile.changePage( "#"+$this.val(), { transition: "slide"} );               
    }
});​​​
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
     <select name="select-choice-5" class="selectMe" data-native-menu="false" tabindex="-1">
        <option>View details...</option>
        <option value="option1">Option1</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="option1">
     <select name="select-choice-5" class="selectMe" data-native-menu="false" tabindex="-1">
        <option>Select an option</option>
        <option value="home">Home</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

​Also your example like is referring to jQM Alpha version, my example is using jQM 1.0.1 version